# Customize Python JSON object_hook

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to customize json data using `object_hook` in Python 3, but do not know how to get started. Any pointers are much appreciated. I am trying to introduce a new key and move existing data into the new key in Python Object.

I am trying to convert below json text:

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "Id": "101",
      "purpose": "xyz text",
      "array": [
        {
          "data": "abcd"
        },
        {
          "data": "ef gh ij"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "102",
      "purpose": "11xyz text",
      "array": [
        {
          "data": "abcd"
        },
        {
          "data": "java"
        },
        {
          "data": "ef gh ij"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "Id": "101",
      "mydata": {
        "purpose": "xyz text",
        "array": [
          {
            "data": "abcd"
          },
          {
            "data": "ef gh ij"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Id": "102",
      "mydata": {
        "purpose": "11xyz text",
        "array": [
          {
            "data": "abcd"
          },
          {
            "data": "java"
          },
          {
            "data": "ef gh ij"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My Python JSON object hook is defined as:

```
class JSONObject:
    def __init__( self, dict ):
        vars(self).update( dict )

    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, 
            sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a custom `object_pairs_hook` (`input_json` is the string with your input JSON).

```
def mydata_hook(obj):
    obj_d = dict(obj)
    if 'Id' in obj_d:
        return {'Id': obj_d['Id'], 'mydata': {k: v for k, v in obj_d.items() if 'Id' not in k}}
    else:
        return obj_d

print(json.dumps(json.loads(input_json, object_pairs_hook=mydata_hook), indent=2))
```

And the output:

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "mydata": {
        "array": [
          {
            "data": "abcd"
          }, 
          {
            "data": "ef gh ij"
          }
        ], 
        "purpose": "xyz text"
      }, 
      "Id": "101"
    }, 
    {
      "mydata": {
        "array": [
          {
            "data": "abcd"
          }, 
          {
            "data": "java"
          }, 
          {
            "data": "ef gh ij"
          }
        ], 
        "purpose": "11xyz text"
      }, 
      "Id": "102"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, works as expected. I will do some reading around object pair hook

Comment: @dcu `json.loads` recursively calls this function to modify the input. If you put `print(obj)` somewhere inside this function you will better understand in what order it being called.